sshpass: invalid option -- 'o' How to Fix this github Action
I have a vps in digital ocean with a node js api running on it. I need to create a simple pipeline to deploy it when I push some changes but Im getting this error:
sshpass: invalid option -- 'o'
Usage: sshpass [-f|-d|-p|-e] [-hV] command parameters
   -f filename   Take password to use from file
   -d number     Use number as file descriptor for getting password
   -p password   Provide password as argument (security unwise)
   -e            Password is passed as env-var "SSHPASS"
   With no parameters - password will be taken from stdin

   -P prompt     Which string should sshpass search for to detect a password prompt
   -v            Be verbose about what you're doing
   -h            Show help (this screen)
   -V            Print version information
At most one of -f, -d, -p or -e should be used

This is my current pipeline:
name: CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Deploy
        run: |
          sshpass -p ${{ secrets.SSH_PASSWORD }} ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${{ secrets.SSH_USER }}@${{ secrets.DROPLET_IP }} << EOF
            cd my-app/server
            git pull origin main
            npm install
            npm run build
            pm2 restart app
          EOF

I have set all my secrets on github so it should not be the problem. any help?

Try single quoting ${{...}} expressions i.e. '${{ secrets.SSH_PASSWORD }}'.
